# If "USE statement is not supported", for Azure Databases, how is the SSMS dropdown able to switch between DBs, how it can work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have some Azure databases. I regularly use Management Studio to execute some commands.

As expected, after some idle time in a query Window, the connection is lost. I connect again and use the menu dropdown to switch between databases. It works, but sometimes is very slow.

In older SQLServer versions, instead of the dropdown was pretty common to write:

```
    USE <database_name>
```

to avoid the dropdown. This is not working anymore, and fails with the following message:

> USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.

But the dropdown works. And the dropdown is just an UI of some command, I guess. Isn't that command a "USE" statement? If not, which statement is it?

Comment: The dropdown is part of the UI and as such benefits from being able to do something your use command can't: it can re-negotiate the connection first (just like you could if you right-click the query window > connection > and enter different server/credentils) and connects directly to the chosen database so it doesn't have to use a USE command at all.

Comment: (And FWIW, that's the way I would do it, when connected to Azure SQL DB try to forget the dropdown even exists, I'm kind of surprised it shows you anything useful enough to "work" anyway.)

Comment: The key point is that SSMS doesn't use a T-SQL statement to change database context for Azure SQL Database.  It just disconnects and reconnects like any other .NET app would.

Comment: Still, is estrange that I connect to "master" as default, then use the dropdown to "use" any of the databases under that connection. Also, when the connection is timed-out and I reconnect, "master" is selected, so I have to use the dropdown again